# Multi Picklist and number fields

Tags: formula-field, multi-select

I'm trying to create a new formula field that gives results as a text by concatenating few fields like multipicklist fields and text fields and numbers fields.

But i have been receiving an error when i'm checking the syntax like
" Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain functions"

I'm trying to concatenate in this way as below by adding a underscore while concatenating

```
"" TEXT(Mutlipicklist1) & "" & TEXT(Mutlipicklist1) & "" & TEXT(Number) 
& "" & TEXT(Number) & "" & TEXT(Checkbox) & "" & TEXT & "_" & TEXT(Picklist)
```

Still the same error

Is it possible to concatenate three different datatype fields?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the details of your formula.  Also, did you click on the "Tell me more" in the error message?  There is a [Tips for Working with Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5) topic in the popup window with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is (provided they can all be transformed into a single type like `text`).

The issue here (as the error indicates) is your multipicklist field. Picklists and Multipicklists are kinda their own thing. To be able to use them in formulas, you generally need to use another function to turn them into something workable.

In this case, you probably just need to wrap that multipicklist field in a `TEXT()` function (to turn it into a string, which you can then concatenate with other things).

`TEXT()`, `CASE()` and `ISPICKVAL()`/`INCLUDES()` are the functions that can work with picklist fields (CASE() and ISPICKVAL() for picklists, INCLUDES() for multipicklists). Looks like there's also `PICKLISTCOUNT()` for multipicklists, but that's probably not what you're looking for here.

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate in this way as below by adding a underscore while concatenating "_"

TEXT(Mutlipicklist1) & "_" & TEXT(Mutlipicklist1) & "_" & text(Number) & "_" & text(Number) & "_" 
& Text(Checkbox) & "_" & Text & "_" & text(Picklist)

Still the same error

Comment: @Dug please add that to your question by making an edit (click the "edit" that appears under the body of your question).

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to concatenate a text field called **Name**, a number field called **Age**, and a multipicklist field called **Interests**, you can use this expression:

> Name + " is " + TEXT(Age) + " years old and likes " + Interests

You can also use the **BR()** function to insert line breaks between the values or use quotation marks to add spaces or punctuation.

For example:

> Name + BR() + "Age: " + TEXT(Age) + BR() + "Interests: " + Interests